# Distance of Bit pairs

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am given a string, and I have to calculate the sum of of each distance of bit pairs where both bits are 1.

For example the given string of 100101 would have the distance of 10
**1**00**1**01 (3)
**1**0010**1** (5)
100**1**0**1** (2)

Therefore the sum of distances is 3+5+2=10.

My current code is the following, I can't really solve what's wrong, and how should I approach the problem.

```
def pairs(s):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == '1':
            for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
                if s[j] == '1':
                    count += 1
    return count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(pairs("100101")) #10
```

I have also tried to store the 1's in a list, but can't manage to calculate the distance.

Comment: You are only adding 1 to `count`, so of course it doesn't give you a correct result. You are just counting the pairs, not summing their distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
def pairs(s):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == '1':
            dist = 0
            for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
                dist += 1
                if s[j] == '1':
                    count += dist
    return count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(pairs("100101")) #10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `itertools.combinations` on indices where the char == 1:

```py
from itertools import combinations

s = "100101"

indices = [i for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch == "1"]
print(sum(b - a for a, b in combinations(indices, 2)))
```

Prints:

```
10
```